# libpng | duplicate symbol for architecture

Tags: c++, macos, qt, libpng

I'm trying to compile a project using libpng on Mac OS X Yosemite.

I got the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_png_create_info_struct", referenced from:
      _writePNG in qrenc.o
  "_png_create_write_struct", referenced from:
      _writePNG in qrenc.o
  "_png_destroy_write_struct", referenced from:
      _writePNG in qrenc.o
  "_png_init_io", referenced from:
      _writePNG in qrenc.o
  "_png_set_IHDR", referenced from:
      _writePNG in qrenc.o
  "_png_set_PLTE", referenced from:
      _writePNG in qrenc.o
  "_png_set_longjmp_fn", referenced from:
      _writePNG in qrenc.o
  "_png_set_pHYs", referenced from:
      _writePNG in qrenc.o
  "_png_set_tRNS", referenced from:
      _writePNG in qrenc.o
  "_png_write_end", referenced from:
      _writePNG in qrenc.o
  "_png_write_info", referenced from:
      _writePNG in qrenc.o
  "_png_write_row", referenced from:
      _writePNG in qrenc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

so I added -lpng to my ld call.
Now it throws

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
    .obj/main.o
    .obj/qrenc.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Same error when linking against libpng installed by homebrew.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that the entire error?

Comment: Nope. I added the complete error output!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two files (probably main.c and qrenc.c) with main function. Remove the function from any of these files and use -lpng.

Comment: ... or `main()` is defined in a header.

Comment: I used a part of a library which still had the cli implemented in it's own main function :)